# subscriber queue length

Tags: ros, queue

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understand that ROS queues all incoming messages until nodes are able to service those callbacks and that this queue length is specified in the constructor of a subscriber.

But what I would like to know is, what happens if the subscriber specifies a queue length that is bigger than what ROS can support? Does the limit depend on some setting in ROS or does it merely depend on the amount of RAM available on the system?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28487/subscriber-queue-length/) by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2012-02-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no limit built into ROS.  It will continue to work until you run out of RAM.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5